# Removing similar, but not identical, lists from a list of lists in python

Tags: python, graph, graph-theory

I am identifying loops in directional graphs. My function returns a list of lists which store the nodes in any loops found.

For instance in a graph where the nodes are connected like this:

```
(1,2)(2,3)(3,4)(3,5)(5,2)
```

a loop is found at 2 - 3 - 5 so the function would return:

```
[[2,3,5]]
```

There are occasions where there are multiple loops which would return something like:

```
[[2,3,4][6,7,8,9]]
```

This is great, but if there are multiple start points in a graph which join the same loop at different points, such as in the graph:

```
(1,2)(2,3)(3,4)(3,5)(5,2)(6,3)
```

both nodes 1 and 6 join the same loop at different points which would return:

```
[[2,3,5][3,5,2]]
```

So here there are two identical loops, which are not identical lists.  I want to identify such duplication and remove all but one (it doesn't matter which).

Note, there may be cases where there are multiple loops, one which is duplicated, such as:

```
[[2,3,5][3,5,2][7,8,9,6]]
```

I've tried looking into itertools:

```
loops.sort()
list(loops for loops,_ in itertools.groupby(loops))
```

but that's not helped, and I'm not 100% sure that this is appropriate anyway.  Any ideas?  I'm on python 2.4.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only care about the elements of each loop, and not the order, I would canonicalize each loop by sorting it, and then take the set:

```
>>> loops = [[2,3,5],[3,5,2],[7,8,9,6]]
>>> set(tuple(sorted(loop)) for loop in loops)
set([(2, 3, 5), (6, 7, 8, 9)])
```

In order to use `set` here you need to convert to a tuple.  You could convert the tuples back to lists, or turn the final set back into a list (maybe even using `sorted` to get a canonical order), but whether you'd actually need to would depend upon what you'd be doing with it.

If you need to preserve path order, I'd canonicalize in a different way:

```
def rotated(l, n):
    return l[n:] + l[:n]

def canonicalize(l):
    m = min(l)
    where = l.index(m)
    return rotated(l, where)
```

and then

```
>>> loops = [[2,5,3], [5,3,2], [7,8,6,9]]
>>> set(tuple(canonicalize(loop)) for loop in loops)
set([(2, 5, 3), (6, 9, 7, 8)])
```

[Edit: note that this simple canonicalization only works if each vertex can only be visited once in a path.]

Comment: I thought that "I want to identify such duplication and remove all but one (it doesn't matter which)" meant to remove the duplicates, but I could certainly be misunderstanding.

Comment: True... The title says something else!

Comment: This seems to meet all of the poster's requirements and is compact. nice!

Comment: Set is weaker than similar, two loops are not similar if they share the same vertices. (1,2,3,4) is not similar to (1,3,2,4).

Comment: @hayden: heh.  You're 100% right, so fortunately the timestamps prove I added my path-sensitive version before your post. :^)

Comment: @DSM sorry, I had not refreshed!

Comment: This is exactly what I was after, perfect thank you.  Sorry about the title confusion, I can see the problem, perhaps 'removing similar or identical lists' or something would have been better.  Either way, spot on, thanks :)

Comment: @Captastic: just to be clear, could you ever visit the same vertex twice in a path?  If so, the above won't work.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to define what similar is, because it is stronger than `set`:

```
def is_similar(X,Y):
    n = len(X)
    return len(Y) == n and any( all( X[i] == Y[(i+j)%n] 
                                     for i in range(n) )
                                for j in range(1,n) ) #the 1 here so that identical lists are not similar
```

The distinction is important as the path (1,2,3,4) is **different** from the path (1,3,2,4), they do not correspond to the same loop.

```
def remove_similars(L):
     new_L = []
     for item in L:
         if not any( is_similar(item, l) for l in new_L ):
             new_L.append(item)
     return new_L
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me: try [[1,2,3],[1,2,3]] or [[1,2,3],[2,3,1]].

Comment: oops, my mistake (I'm missing an any)... - fixed. Note: In this one [[1,2,3],[1,2,3]] returns [[1,2,3],[1,2,3]] (this is intended).

Comment: +1, but I don't quite see why you choose to define similarity this way.  If we're assuming identity under cyclic rotation to get rid of (2,3,1), then wouldn't we get rid of the second (1,2,3)?  OTOH, if we just want to canonicalize but preserve multiplicity, then shouldn't we give back [[1,2,3],[1,2,3]] for [[1,2,3], [2,3,1]]?  Hopefully the OP will comment on the goals.

Comment: @DSM well the reason (I thought) was that if you want to remove all loops, if there are two loops which are the same (1,2,3,1,2,3) you want to remove the (1,2,3) and the (1,2,3) not the (2,3,1). Although when I actually think about it I think this algorithm is hopelessly naive :s

Comment: @DSM I think I have misunderstood the objective. Ah well :)

Answer (score 0):

You could take a `set` of each of your lists. If two sets are equal, then you have a duplicated loop. You're losing the order of the nodes in the loop, though, but does it matter to you ?